# How to prevent the last bibliography entry from being split in a new page?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, page-breaking

I'm currently facing the problem that when the last bibliography entry on a page is too long to fit in the remaining space, it's being split in two parts (in the current and the next page).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}
\begin{document}


\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

I already tried the following, which was suggested in the posting [Preventing page breaks from occurring in bibliography items](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91686/92620), but it doesn't affect the page breaks for long bib entries.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\clubpenalty4000}{\clubpenalty10000}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\widowpenalty4000}{\clubpenalty10000}{}{}
```

How to prevent the last bibliography entry on a page from being split in a new page ?

Comment: \parskip=0pt plus 1fil

Comment: Its works, thanks! But now the declaration of academic honesty, which follows after the references, is spaced wrong (huge break between chapter title and text

Comment: Reset \parskip back to original value (usually 0pt, but check using \the\parskip) after the bibiliography.  This really only works when you have lots of small paragraphs.  You may need a \vfill\null at the end as well.

Comment: i have the same problem can any one provide a clear answer or command to add?

Comment: There's a mistake in the patch of `\widowpenalty`. Can you spot it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might try

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\interlinepenalty=10000}
```

Setting the parameters `\clubpenalty` and `\widowpenalty` to `10000` (the practical equivalent of infinity...) will prevent typographic "orphans" ("clubs" in TeX jargon) and "widows". However, if an entry is four or more lines long, these penalties will not disallow a page break after the first two lines and/or the final two lines of the typeset entry. Hence the suggestion to reset `\interlinepenalty`.

Comment: It works for me, what's good is that it only affect  thebibliography environment, thanks.

Comment: Works for me as well! Bibliography looks much better now. Thanks for your help!