# How to prevent a page break in a bib item?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, page-breaking

I'm making an annotated bibliography like the following MWE, thanks to [moewe's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/587256/169454). I would like to prevent a page break in a bib item, though the page break between the items is tolerable. [A similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91686/169454) has already been resolved, but the question and answers seems to be related to `natbib` and I need solutions for `biblatex`.

I tried to use wrap an item with `vbox`, but in vain.
Do you have any idea?

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend = biber, style = apa, citestyle = numeric]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{annotation}{%
  \ifboolexpr{       test {\iffieldundef{annotation}}
              or not togl {bbx:annotation}}
    {}
    {\begingroup
      \togglefalse{blx@bibliography}%
      \newline
      \setunit{}%
      \printfield{annotation}%
      \endgroup}
  \iffieldundef{abstract}
    {}
    {\begingroup
      \togglefalse{blx@bibliography}%
      \setunit{%
        \par
        \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}}%
      \bibstring[\mkbibbold]{abstract}%
      \setunit{\newline}%
      \printfield{abstract}%
      \endgroup}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
    {\list
      %\vbox{
      {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
          \printfield{labelprefix}%
          \printfield{labelnumber}}}
      {%\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
        \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
        \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}% %\bibitemsep
        \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
        \setlength{\itemindent}{0\labelsep}%
        \setlength{\listparindent}{0\labelsep}%
        }%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
      %}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Manual{R-rmarkdown,
  title    = {rmarkdown: Dynamic Documents for {R}},
  author   = {JJ Allaire and Yihui Xie and Jonathan McPherson
              and Javier Luraschi and Kevin Ushey and Aron Atkins
              and Hadley Wickham and Joe Cheng and Winston Chang
              and Richard Iannone},
  year     = {2020},
  note     = {R package version 2.3},
  url      = {https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown},
  abstract = {This is a good book. That's why I cite this.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
              sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
              Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
              laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}
}
@Book{knitr2015,
  title = {Dynamic Documents with {R} and knitr},
  author = {Yihui Xie},
  publisher = {Chapman and Hall/CRC},
  address = {Boca Raton, Florida},
  year = {2015},
  edition = {2nd},
  note = {ISBN 978-1498716963},
  url = {https://yihui.org/knitr/},
  abstract = {This is a good book. That's why I cite this.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{R-rmarkdown, knitr2015}

\printbibliography[title=References]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want your `\par` to allow a page break, issue a `\nopagebreak` after it ([What is the difference between \nobreak and \nolinebreak?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94217/35864)).

If you don't want line breaks to occur between 'normal' lines in your bibliography, increase `\interlinepenalty` to 10,000 ([How to avoid page-breaks inside paragraphs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21983/35864)). The value is set in `\bibsetup`, so we append the new value to that macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend = biber, style = apa, citestyle = numeric]{biblatex}

\appto{\bibsetup}{%
  \interlinepenalty=100000\relax}
  
\renewbibmacro*{annotation}{%
  \ifboolexpr{       test {\iffieldundef{annotation}}
              or not togl {bbx:annotation}}
    {}
    {\begingroup
     \togglefalse{blx@bibliography}%
     \newline
     \setunit{}%
     \printfield{annotation}%
     \endgroup}%
  \iffieldundef{abstract}
    {}
    {\begingroup
     \togglefalse{blx@bibliography}%
     \setunit{%
       \par\nopagebreak
       \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}}%
     \bibstring[\mkbibbold]{abstract}%
     \setunit{\newline}%
     \printfield{abstract}%
     \endgroup}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@manual{R-rmarkdown,
  title    = {rmarkdown: Dynamic Documents for {R}},
  author   = {J. J. Allaire and Yihui Xie and Jonathan McPherson
              and Javier Luraschi and Kevin Ushey and Aron Atkins
              and Hadley Wickham and Joe Cheng and Winston Chang
              and Richard Iannone},
  year     = {2020},
  note     = {R package version 2.3},
  url      = {https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown},
  abstract = {This is a good book. That's why I cite this.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
              sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
              Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
              laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.},
}
@book{knitr2015,
  title     = {Dynamic Documents with {R} and knitr},
  author    = {Yihui Xie},
  publisher = {Chapman and Hall/CRC},
  address   = {Boca Raton, Florida},
  year      = {2015},
  edition   = {2nd},
  note      = {ISBN 978-1498716963},
  url       = {https://yihui.org/knitr/},
  abstract  = {This is a good book. That's why I cite this.
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
               sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
               Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
               laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

\nocite{R-rmarkdown, knitr2015}

\printbibliography[title=References]
\end{document}
```